# Regex to convert htmlspecialchars escaped characters back

Tags: php, regex, htmlspecialchars

I take user input on my website and I allow formatting through a WYSIWYG editor.

Now I run the entire post I get in PHP through htmlspecialchars with ENT_quotes.

From there I would like to run a regex to convert my allowed rules back to real html.

So that

```
&lt;p&gt;TEXT&lt;/p&gt;
```

Thanks!

becomes

```
<p>TEXT</p>
```

Is there way to do this with regex? I am not familair with it. But basically look for the escaped tags and replace them with real tags, while keeping everything in the middle?

Edit: I want the regex to make the valid HTML codes. First I run the entire thing through `htmlspecialchars` to be 100% secure and get entities version of all < & > characters. Then I want a regex to convert ONLY the tags I want back to normal. I do not want to decode all entities back to their regular, I only want to decode the tags I want. so for example a regex search for `&lt;p&gt;TEXT&lt;/p&gt;` back to `<p>TEXT</p>` - I don't want to reconvert just the `<`, `&`, `>` themselves. I want to reconvert only the tags I want. Which in this example is the paragraph tags.

Comment: I want it to be valid HTML. I run the entire thing through htmlspecialchars first to be 100% secure. Then I want a regex to convert ONLY the tags I want back to normal.

Comment: It is an example. I want the encoded version of '<p>TEXT</p>' which is '&lt;p&gt;TEXT&lt;/p&gt;' after htmlspecialchars to become REAL html '<p>TEXT</p>'

This way I have encoding all user input to entities. Then using a regex to code back only tags I want back to real html.

Comment: No attributes allowed. All quotes get escaped with htmlspecialchars ent_quotes.

I don't want to make quotes back to their real version. Only use a reged to find the encoded version of <p> with any text between that ends with encoded version of </p> and make it back to real html.

Comment: @Incognito:  Have you considered using `strip_tags()` instead?  Although it's far from being a perfect solution, it is actually much cleaner and simpler, and doesn't allow someone to bypass it by pre-encoding the tags (easy hack to bypass your method).

Comment: The issue is, even if they pre-encode the tags. It's only searching for the full encoded version of the tag '&lt;p&gt;TEXT&lt;/p&gt;' can only every become <p>TEXT</p> It will almost be like a bbcode at that point. They wouldnt be able to add attributes or use other tags. Hence I want to search for the full regex with text inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex should work for what you've decribed:

```
/&lt;(\/?)(allowed_tags_here_seperated_by_|)&gt;/
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uX7cT1/1
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/579884

PHP Usage:

```
$allowed_tags = array('p', 'h1');
$regex = '/&lt;(\/?)(' . implode('|', $allowed_tags) . ')&gt;/';
$test_string = '&lt;p&gt;TEXT&lt;/p&gt; This & that don\'t < decode > these though <h2> &lt;h1&gt; &lt;p class=&quot;test&quot;&gt;';
echo preg_replace($regex, '<$1$2>', $test_string);
```

Oh, this also doesn't take into account self closing elements. `<br />`, `<hr />`, `<img stuff />`, etc.

Comment: I won't have any self-closing elements so that's fine. I made my editor not use <br> or line breaks. 

That looks awsome and it's almost exactly what I want. But I don't think it's searching for an ending tag?

I want to look for both the start and ending tag... then decode them and keep everything in middle. Does that make sense? That way if someone enters <h4> and does not close the tag, it won't just make all the text on the page a giant heading.

Comment: It searches for closing elements, it doesn't care if there are opening ones though. For that maybe something like, https://regex101.com/r/uX7cT1/2 would work?

Comment: Thanks that worked, I can't upvote yet. (not enough rep) But you are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Issue with that, is it converts ALL characters back. I htmlspecialchars the entire original output. Then the stuff I want, p, strong, blockquote, etc I want to convert back to real html>

That way everything is escaped minsu the stuff I allow.